# Value is not updated when saving, after javascript calculations

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

i have couple `textboxes` on my form. Few expenses and a balance.

I use javascript to calculate the balance when the expense `textboxes` get changed like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    // add up main numbers
    $("input[class*='add']").change(function (event) {
        var sum = 0;
        var subsum = 0;
        var num = 0;
        $("input[class*='add']").each(function (event) {
            num = parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
            sum = sum + num;
        });
        $("input[class*='minus']").each(function (event) {
            num = parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
            sum = sum - num;
        });
        $("input[class*='addcost']").each(function (event) {
            num = parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
            subsum = subsum + num;
        });
        var balance = $("input[id*='txtBegBal']").val() - sum;
        $("input[id*='txtEnding']").val(balance);
        $("input[id*='txtTotalCost']").val(subsum);
    });
```

the results show correct on screen, however when I click on "save", the `txtTotalCost` still shows the value, before `javascript` has updated it, so it does not get saved correctly.

could someone please point me in the right direction?

I do all my populating within the   `if (!Page.IsPostBack)`. The values that I change for "expenses" get passed in just fine, it's just the calculated field that is not.

Comment: where are rest codes which is saving the changes. And what is happening on save click..

Comment: Could you possibly put together a jsfiddle showing that it isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess here but is the txtTotalCost disabled?
Disabled text fields will not update like this because the client browser doesn't send the form data back to the server when it is disabled. In that case, you'll get the old value that is in viewstate. Try enabling it, or you could use a label and a hidden input field.

Answer (score 0):

The second suggestion is that your fields haven't exist yet. Try to use

```
 $("input[class*='add']").on('change', function() { 
     // your code here 
 });
```